# Importing new projects from GitHub changes Android Gradle Settings

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I have an issue with Gradle in Android Studio. Every time I import a new project from GitHub there are lot of notifications from Android Studio to update many things and even though I cancel all of them few things get updated on it's own such as coding style and other things.

For example recently I imported a project and then worked on that project for few days but after few days when I tried opening my existing Android projects there are some unknown errors with Gradle, Kotlin Kapt and all things.

I want to know is there any easiest way to keep track of your default Android Studio settings and every time you import a project only than only settings for that project are changed and not for entire Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

you should download the project offline and go to the `build.gradle(project-level module)` and update classpath dependency for example `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'` after this go to `gradle -> wrapper ->gradle-wrapper` and update `distributionUrl` for example `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip`
and finally you can open your project in **Android Studio**.